# How can we determine object type class while creating dynamic conditional class in java

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have factory class to create object based on my conditional term, but i unable to create it because i need to declare which class i want to use meanwhile the class i use based on my rule condition. How to solve this?

CustomerFactory.class

```
public class CustomerFactory {

    public CustomerBuyer getType(String type) {
        if(type == "buyer") {
            CustomerBuyer<DataDetailBuy> myCustomer = new CustomerBuyer();
            myCustomer.setName("buyer1");
            myCustomer.getDataDetail().setItemCode("ITEM001");
            return myCustomer;
        }else if(type == "seller"){
            CustomerBuyer<DataDetailSell> myCustomer = new CustomerBuyer();
            return myCustomer;
        }       


    }
}
```

CustomerBuyer.class

```
public class CustomerBuyer<T> {

    public String name;
    public T dataDetail;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public T getDataDetail() {
        return dataDetail;
    }
    public void setDataDetail(T dataDetail) {
        this.dataDetail = dataDetail;
    }


}
```

App.java

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        CustomerFactory customerFactory = new CustomerFactory();

        CustomerBuyer person1 = customerFactory.getType("buyer");

        person1.getName();
        person1.getDataDetail();

        CustomerBuyer person2 = customerFactory.getType("seller");

        person2.getName();
        person2.getDataDetail().getProfit();

    }

}
```

The function `getType` on CustomerFactory has error, because the return class type is dynamic. How to tell the function to accept return dynamic type class based on my condition? On the other side the class type is chosen while in runtime

**Note: `<T>` generic class i want to assign with different class each condition**

Comment: Generic types are deleted in runtime by something Type Erasure in Java. I suggest you create separate classes for each type.

Comment: @Omid.N if i create seperate class for each condition how about the return type i have to use? if seperate class it means dynamic too

Comment: Create a superclass and extend it by both of them and the return type will be the superclass.

Comment: @Omid.N it means abstract class or regular class?

Comment: Can be both but if you make it abstract it is more "Object-Oriented".

Comment: @Omid.N Im still having problem with the class `myCustomer.getDataDetail()` cant be called because the type of DataDetail is dynamic. How to make the type return value of my superclass need to be dynamic too beside using generic class?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213838/discussion-between-ferry-sanjaya-and-omid-n).